# Expected variant allele frequency of mutation present on 2 out of 3 copies of a 70% purity cancer sample

Tags: cancer, mutations, allele

I am reading [Nik-Zainal et al., 2012](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/22608083/).

In such paper, (for sample PD4120a - a 188-fold depth ER+ breast cancer tumor), it is stated that:

- The sample has 70% tumor purity.
- The genome has one triploid chromosomal region.

The final point I don't understand is why "mutations occurring on the triploid chromosomal region before duplication would be present on two of three copies - **with an expected variant allele fraction of ~55%**."

If I correctly understood VAF calculation, such mutations should have expected VAF of $2/3 p$, where p is the purity. Therefore, $0.7*2/3=46.7\%$.

Why is this different from the reported expected VAF?

Comment: Migrated from Bioinformatics SE at author request

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry I did not read the article. But in the case that it is only the tumor which has the duplicated chromosomal region, I think you will have an increased contribution of the mutation relative to the normal. I'll try to illustrate with an example:

Let's say the total sampled number of cells is 100. Tumor purity makes it 30 normal cells and 70 tumor cells.

30 normal cells contributes 2 normal copies: 60

70 tumor cells contributes 1 normal copy and 2 mutated copies: 70 and 140

If we calculate the expected frequency of the somatic mutation we get:
140 / (60 + 70 + 140) = ~ 52%

Still not 55! But it's the best guess I have.

Comment: Thank you, this does indeed make sense. I will see if anyone else has a closer results + explanation.